# precedence of ++ (post,prefix) nd dereference operator

Tags: c

Shouldn't the output of the following code be `f`

I get an output `e`

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main(){

    char arr[]="Geeks";
    char *ptr = arr;
    ++*ptr++;
    printf("%c\n",*ptr);

}
```

Comment: Don't you have somebody that reviews your code and gives you a sharp rap on the knuckles with a ruler every time you write code like this?  Don't code alone.

Comment: @qarma No, he doesn't increment anything twice.

Comment: @qarma Nothing is incremented twice in `++*ptr++`. In fact, I once pondered using this very expression as an example in a space-constrained article. I eventually decided against it, FWIW.

Comment: sorry I was imprecise.

Answer (score 4):

No, it shouldn't. Your code increments the first character and then moves the pointer one forward. The pointer will point to the first `e`, and depending on your locale/character encoding, the first letter is most probably `H`. The expression is parsed [according to precedence and associativity rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence) as:

```
++(*(p++))
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes expression is parsed as ++*******((ptr++)),  first ptr++ is calculated but because it is postfix increment the new calculated value doesn't update the old value of ptr until the statement ends (;) . Next ++**(  ptr++  ) is calculated on old value of ptr that result , G change to H. Now all work is done, the statement ends and ptr value is updated, that points to next element that is e.