# Explanation of output of a C program

Tags: c, language-lawyer, operator-precedence

The following program gives output:

```
hffltgpshfflt
```

Can somebody explain this how does operator precedence of postfix++,prefix++ and dereference(*) operators decide this output?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  char arr[]  = "geeksforgeeks";
  char *ptr  = arr;

  while(*ptr != '\0')
   ++*ptr++;
  printf("%s %s", arr, ptr);

  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @JoachimPileborg ok retracting the close vote here -- you're right in this case, the prefix ++ binds to the dereferenced ptr. Just adding ... why the hell write such code? But ok, let's say it's a lab example or something like this ...

Comment: @MartinJames: Not really ...

Comment: Just adding I really had to put parenthesis manually (like Joachim did in his answer) to understand it's *not* the same memory location modified by the two `++` in this example. It's definitely code nobody would ever want to see in "production". :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Precedence and associativity of prefix and postfix in c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27276159/precedence-and-associativity-of-prefix-and-postfix-in-c). Similarly, [precedence of ++ (post,prefix) nd dereference operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16775012/precedence-of-post-prefix-nd-dereference-operator)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy once one learn the [operator precedence and associativity](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) rules.

You expression `++*ptr++` is equivalent to `++*(ptr++)` which is equivalent to `++(*(ptr++))`.

So the order of operations is

1. The post-increment operator (which returns the old value of the pointer `ptr`)
2. The dereferencing of the pointer `ptr` (before the pointer is incremented)
3. The prefix-increment of the result of the dereference, increasing the value pointed to by `ptr`, turning e.g. `'g'` to `'h'` etc.
4. The pointer `ptr` is incremented (actually part of step 1)